# Visual Studio replacement for C++ Windows apps

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio

I wanted to ask, if there is any good replacement for microsoft visual studio. I want to make windows apps, i mean normal window with sliders, buttons and input, but so far i was using only visual studio and c# in school, but i want to try C++ and something maybe even free in home. Any1 know anything like that?

Visual studio lets you just put a button using interface, then double click it, and you are right there to code button functionality, thats convinient, and i would love something similar.

Comment: Doesn't Visual Studio support C++ ?

Comment: There's a C++ version of the Visual Studio Express editions.

Comment: When you download/install VIsual Studio express it gives you a language choice, Choose C++ you get what you want. Express only allows you to develop in one language using the IDE. If you want to switch, you'll have to unistall and do it again, or have more than one machine.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson that's not true, I have Visual C++ 2010 Express and Visual C# 2010 Express running alongside each other just fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply download [Visual C++ 2010 Express](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/visual-cpp-express).

Answer (score 1):

You could try [SharpDevelop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/Default.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

When you mention Visual Studio you probably mean Visual C# projects. So you may use the same environment to start a C++/CLR project and use it very much like C# projects before.

One more option would be to use Embarcadero C++Builder. It still offers similar workflow as Visual Studio for some known reason but does not depend on .Net. Additionally the latest edition (XE2) offers a new framework that allows creation of source code portable applications between Windows and Mac and probably Linux in the future. It is not free though and the cheapest starter edition costs 150$ moreover there is a 30 days free trial as well.

Answer (score 1):

you can try the Netbeans IDE, which is free and supports developing the GUI applications as similar to Visual Studio. It provides the same facility like drag and drop of controls. you can use JAVA or even c++ for this.

Answer (score 1):

Free and cross-platform IDE:

[Qt Creator](http://qt.nokia.com/products/developer-tools/) is a cross-platform integrated development environment (IDE) tailored to the needs of Qt developers. It provides:

- C++ and JavaScript code editor
- Integrated UI designer
- Project and build management tools
- gdb and CDB debuggers
- Support for version control
- Simulator for mobile UIs
- Support for desktop and mobile targets